# installing sdl2 with cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, sdl-2, cabal-install

I am trying to install the SDL2 package for Haskell via Cabal under windows.
And after some rather tedious configuration, I am getting this error:

```
C:\Users\kaervin>cabal install sdl2 --extra-include-dirs=C:\SDL2-2.0.3\include --extra-lib-dirs=C:\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring sdl2-1.3.1...
Building sdl2-1.3.1...
Failed to install sdl2-1.3.1
Last 10 lines of the build log ( C:\Users\kaervin\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\sdl2-1.3.1.log ):
C:\Users\kaervin\AppData\Local\Temp\sdl2-1.3.1-8956\sdl2-1.3.1\dist\doc\html\sdl2
doesn't exist or isn't a directory
sdl2-1.3.1: library-dirs: /usr/local/cross-tools/i686-w64-mingw32/lib is a
relative path which makes no sense (as there is nothing for it to be relative
to). You can make paths relative to the package database itself by using
${pkgroot}. (use --force to override)
sdl2-1.3.1: include-dirs: /usr/local/cross-tools/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2
is a relative path which makes no sense (as there is nothing for it to be
relative to). You can make paths relative to the package database itself by
using ${pkgroot}. (use --force to override)
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
sdl2-1.3.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I am using:

```
C:\Users\kaervin>cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.18.0.5
using version 1.18.1.3 of the Cabal library
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: That's a [standing issue](https://github.com/haskell-game/sdl2/issues/43).

Comment: That seems to be a different issue though.
I got the whole pkg-config working, and now am getting this error.